# The function of glycerine in fondant

Tags: fondant

What is the function of glyceine in fondant?

Is there a specific grade of glycerine used for fondant?  I ask this because the one I buy in the bakery store looks no different than the one I see among cosmetics

Answer (score 1):

Glycerine's functionality is a "moisturizer", in that it's very good at keeping moisture for a long period. In the case of fondant, it will help to keep it pliable for a longer period and help to minimize drying out too quickly when working with it (rolling out, icing sugar/cornstarch, application). It also slightly helps any sugars from crystallizing, which as you can guess, fondant has a LOT of sugar.

Note: It's the same glycerine in the cosmetic aisle.

Comment: *Note: It's the same glycerine in the cosmetic aisle.* Are you sure that's been processed in a food-safe way? With no non-food additives? (A random hit on Amazon states "Do not consume. For external use only.")

Comment: In a pure state, unless labelled otherwise, yes, glycerine is glycerine.

Comment: But the labeling rules for cosmetics are nothing like as strict as for food (in many places). In particular there's no need to warn about cross contamination with allergens if it's not intended for consumption, and I have seen such warnings on culinary glycerin.

Comment: Without seeing an example of the bottle in question, you're just speculating for the sake of arguing. Glycerine is glycerine. If it's specifically intended for cosmetic use, one can assume the bottle will say that on the front label. If it's intended for food grade, it'll be labelled as such. If it's just pure glyercine, it can be used for either.

Comment: @StevenXavier glycerine in the "cosmetic aisle" is not food grade and shouldn't be used for cooking as it may contain additives not suitable for consumption.

Comment: One would assume it would be labelled on the package. Pure glycerine in the baking aisle and pure glycerine in the cosmetics aisle would theoretically be the same.